# Differentiability for arcsin and limits[Question]

Tags: trigonometry, inverse

So continuing from the title; I have a question regarding the arcsin.
In my book it says that the inverse of sin is  differentiable only on the open interval $(-1,1)$ Which I can understand.

However, later they claim that the slope of the graph approaches infinity when 
$x->-1+$ or as $x->1-$

And following the formula for the derivative for arcsin

$\frac{d}{dx}arcsin=\frac{1}{sqrt{1-x^2}}$

I can see that. Although, would't it mean there has to be a asymptote at $x=-1$ and $x=1$ if the slope appraoches infinity at $x->-1+$ or as $x->1-$?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you [look at the graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arcsin+x), you'll notice that $\arcsin(x)$ is bounded on $[-1,1]$, so there can't be an asymptote.

Asymptotes occur when the *function* approaches infinity. Here, the *derivative* of the function approaches infinity. A similar thing happens with $\sqrt[3]{x}$ at $x = 0$. Does [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E(1%2F3)) look like it has an asymptote?

Comment: What is the explanation behind it? While it makes sense for the derivative to appraoch infinity when x aproaches either end. It does't as much when looking at the graph?

Comment: @oxodo: Then you're not looking close enough. If you zoom in a little, the graph certainly looks vertical at the endpoints $x=\pm 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the tangent line at that points is vertical but there are not 
asymptotes.

It’s analogue at the situation for $f(x)=\sqrt x$ at x=0.

Comment: I see your point. But how would you explain that? While it makes sense as a function it does't when looking at it. Thank you btw

Comment: Consider that at the corresponding point for the function sinx you have an horizontal tangent line ( precisely at $x=\pm \frac{\pi}2$) thus in the graph of the inverse the tangent line is vertical. As for $y=x^2$ in $x=0$ and its inverse $\sqrt x$ at $x=0$.